# TFS2013 branch references missing

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm finally moving my project from a linear "use TFS as a backup" solution, to a true source control solution and learning along the way....

I had so many issues with the current solution in my TFS server that I decided to re-create a new master tree and go from there.  (I'm not worried about compiling an earlier version)

I create a master branch uploaded my source into TFS2013 and then branched it into a dev branch.  My first issue was with nuget, but I was able to resolve that with setting the packages to download automatically.

However, I have a lot of third party DLLs that did not get pushed into source and were missing when I went to compile the dev branch.

I'm sure this question has been asked before but nothing is coming up with the searches I've done thus far (probably because I don't know the proper terminology)

Why are these third party DLLs not showing up when I branch the project?

Comment: source control systems aren't supposed to store binary files, so they don't by default. try rebranching / merging your dependencies folder

Comment: Are you using git or TFVC for version control?